# .htaccess Rewrite whole dir contents to another

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, nginx

I am trying to rewrite the whole contents of a directory to the home url.

so, if someone visits `www.example.com/bnn27sh32j@d299/gold` it should take them to `www.example.com/gold`

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^bnn27sh32j@d299/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

doesnt work, maybe its because it has the illegal characters in the dir name?

Comment: Here is a similar problem on StackOverflow where somebody is trying to rewrite an encoded `@`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130493/allow-percentage-symbol-in-mod-rewrite

Comment: What other rewrite rules do you have in place?   It could be a conflict of some kind.  The order of the rules could be an issue.

Comment: There is nothing "illegal" about the `@` (at) character - if that is what you are implying? (Although you mention "character**s**"? What other "illegal" characters are there?) The `@` character is nothing special, it does not need to be URL encoded in the path part of the URL and is matched as a literal character by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (even if it was URL encoded in the request). FWIW, your `RewriteRule` directive by itself looks OK, so maybe there is a conflict elsewhere in your `.htaccess` file, as @Stephen suggests?

Comment: However, you've tagged your question `nginx`? `RewriteRule` and `.htaccess` are an Apache mechanism and will obviously not work on Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/bnn27sh32j@d299/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1
```

It takes http://www.example.com/bnn27sh32j@d299/gold and redirects to http://www.example.com/gold.

Before implementing, you can test the rule here: https://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: Although this is really no different to the rule stated in the question? (If one works then so should the other, except for conflicts with other directives).